# What does the Syntax error : operator expected mean in caml?

Tags: ocaml, caml

So I was writing my code to make a certain loop but I got that error when running it and don't understand why... Can someone explain me what's the problem here please.

```
for k = 0 to 10 do
for i = 0 to 10 do (let a = ref 0 ; a := !a + k*i mod 17) done ;
!a ;
done ;;
```

And here the error message :

```
# for k = 0 to 10 do
Line 4, characters 57-58:
4 |  for i = 0 to 10 do (let a = ref 0 ; a := !a + k*i mod 17); done ;
                                                         ^
Error: Syntax error: operator expected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted it's not a very enlightening error message. However your problem is that you have `let` with no maching `in`. Except at the outermost level of a module, every `let` must be matched by `in`.

You can change `let a = ref 0 ;` to `let a = ref 0 in` and should get a little farther.

There are some other problems here, but this is your immediate problem, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your response I suspected it was it.